# How to add free text and callout comment features on PDF.js web viewer?

Tags: pdf.js

I know Mozilla **PDF.js** is used only for PDF viewer purpose. By using some open source codes like (annotations) I have created some **highlight, underline and strikeout** features over PDF viewer.

Now I want to implement the **free text and callout** features to be added on top of it. Also while performing an annotation I want to retrieve the co-ordinates of PDF where the annotation is added.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This one called Annotationeer has free text. https://annotationeer.netlify.com/ and it uses div layer. I somehow find it hard to do free text rendering in the canvas because of font issues. easier if you do them as dom.